# how to solve $2(2y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=y^3+1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

how can I solve $2(2y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=y^3+1$

I got by $x=\frac{y^3+1}{2}$ that $y=\frac{x^3+1}{2}$ but I was told earlier that can't say that $x=y$.

So I can I solve this equation?

Thanks.

Comment: Cube both sides, simplify the expression. Note that y = 1 is a root.

Comment: Raise it somehow midway to get low as possible?

Comment: You can't simplify with $x=y$ in general, but in this particular case you can.

Answer (score 5):

You correctly set $x^3=2y-1$, so the equation becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
2y=x^3+1\\
2x=y^3+1
\end{cases}
$$
Subtract them:
$$
2(y-x)=x^3-y^3
$$
or
$$
(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)+2(x-y)=0
$$
This factors as
$$
(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+2)=0
$$
but the second factor is positive for all $x$ and $y$, because $x^2+xy+y^2\ge0$.

Therefore you conclude $x=y$, so plugging in the equation $2y=x^3+1$ you get
$$
x^3-2x+1=0
$$
that's easy to solve because it factors as $(x-1)(x^2+x-1)=0$.

---

There is a different way to solve the particular problem, but using more general principles (thanks to ivancho for having suggested it).

Your equation is in the form
$$
f^{-1}(y)=f(y)
$$
where
$$
f(y)=\frac{y^3+1}{2}
$$
is an increasing function (hence invertible) taking on every real value. Decreasing would be the same, of course.

If $y$ is a solution of your equation and we set $x=f(y)$, then from $f^{-1}(y)=f(y)$ we get $f^{-1}(y)=x$ and so $y=f(x)$.

Suppose $(x,y)$ is a solution of $x=f(y)$ and $y=f(x)$. If we had $x<y$, then, by the fact that $f$ is increasing, we would have
$$
f(x)<f(y)
$$
so $y<x$. Similarly, from $x>y$ we get $f(x)>f(y)$ or $y>x$. In both cases we get a contradiction.

Comment: This is definitely the right way (rather than plugging nonics in WolframAlpha). I have a slight improvement to your argument - since $f(x)=\frac {x^3+1} {2}$ is strictly monotonic, and we have $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=x$, then assuming $x<y => f(x)<f(y) => y<x$ contradiction, similarly $y<x$ doesn't work, so $x=y$

Comment: I am not sure how do you arrive to $2x=y^3+1$? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MonK If we set $x=\sqrt[3]{2y-1}$, then it's just the given equation, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

By cubing you get

$$ y^9+3 y^6+3 y^3 - 16 y + 9 = 0$$

It factors (using Wolfram alpha) into

$$ (y-1) (y^2+y-1) (y^6+2 y^4+2 y^3+4 y^2+2 y+9) = 0$$

According to WA, all the roots of the last polynomial are complex. The second one has $ \frac{(-1-\sqrt{5})}{2}$ and $ \frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)}{2}$ as roots. I don't know if you can get exact forms for the other (complex) roots.

Comment: Solutions given by WA shouldn't even be considered. In fact, they should be plainly forbidden. They give you the answer, but do not enlighten you any bit about how to get it.

Comment: @AlexM. You make my day writing this comment ! Thank you.

Comment: @Alex To be fair, I find this answer to be a more systematic way of solving the question than to notice that the equation is $$f(f(x))=x$$ with $f(x)=\frac{x^3+1}2$ (noticing this is very hard!)

Answer (score 0):

Letting $t=\sqrt[3]{2y-1}$ we have $y=\dfrac{t^3+1}2$ . Replacing, we have a [nonic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Names_of_polynomials_by_degree) in *t*, which has $t=1$ and $t=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt5}2$ among its roots, the remaining six belonging to an irreducible sextic, all of which are complex.